# Does boost geometry support curved geometries?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

Is it possible to construct [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) using boost geometry?

I want to check does the rectangle overlap with the circular sector, as shown on the image below.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean _spherical geometry_ or just arc sectors of circles / ellipses?

Comment: As far I can see from their [models](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/models.html) you can only use approximated polygons for the latter. _Spherical geometries_ (like e.g. on the surface of a 3d sphere) are supported as far I've seen.

Comment: Hi, @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for looking it up. I need arc sectors of circles / ellipses.

Comment: So, as mentioned you'll need to find a way to provide a sufficiently approximated polygon to build the arc sector. Generally it shouldn't matter if you work with an approximation, the numbers converge quite quickly for regular polygon shapes. On the other hand I suspect, the more points you have to describe a polygon, the more time will be needed to perform the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

It's explciitly not possible. It is also explicitly documented how to e.g. use the `buffer` algorithm to generate a circle with a given radius from a point:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/strategies/strategy_buffer_point_circle.html

However, you will have to apply intersections to end up with the linesegments (a linestring concepts) that fall inside a given shape to get parts of that circle.